# Need help executing VBScript on 32bit and 64bit machines

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run the following code:

```
 Dim objShell  'Creates Windows Shell Object
   set objShell = Nothing

     objShell.run \\omserver\netlogon\Mater2kupdate.bat
```

It has ran fine for several years (when we were running Windows 32bit). But now we are changing the OS to Windows 64bit. When I run this same code I'm getting an error message that says:

[Error message says Script: C:\Users\username\Desktop\filename.vbs Line:5 Char:4 Error: Object required Code: 800A01A8 Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKEPb.png)

(I hope the picture uploaded so you can see the error message).

I've done some searching on this error message and it looks like the error is because I'm trying to run the code on 64bit machines. I've tried looking for how to write this so it will work on either 32bit or 64bit, but I don't understand any of the examples enough to use them. I realized that I will have to modify the code that I find so it works for me, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to figure it out. Can you help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: What is on line 5 of the script?  You should include the relevant script code in your question.

Comment: Surround the path with quotes. and you set objShell to nothing then attempt to run it......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a breakdown

```
Dim objShell  'Creates Windows Shell Object - NO It declares a variable of the type Variant
set objShell = Nothing 'releases the object...but you never instantiated the object

 objShell.run \\omserver\netlogon\Mater2kupdate.bat -'will fail as objShell is nothing
```

You need to instatiate the Wscript.Shell then you can use the Run method of it.

```
Dim objShell  'declare a variable to hold our Windows Shell Object
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

 objShell.run "\\omserver\netlogon\Mater2kupdate.bat"
```

Comment: Thank you Rich, you were correct!  That's what I get for trying to do it quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much Rich! That worked wonderfully. You are the best.